# Angular 2 Get child routes of Lazy Load Routes

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading

I have an App module with lazy load defined routes:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule', component: CoreComponent, data: {showInMenu: false, role: 'ROLE_USER'}},
    { path: 'admin', loadChildren: 'app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule', component: CoreComponent, data: {showInMenu: true, role: 'ROLE_ADMIN'}},
];
```

In Admin module I have defined admins' routes:

```
export const adminRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: AdminDashboardComponent},
    { path: 'areas', component: ManageAreasComponent}
];
```

I would like to know if it is possible to get the routes of admin ('' and 'areas') before I load the module? What I would like to achieve is the next: I would like to have modules lazy loaded, but when you open the application, I would like to show applications main menu which should display also second level navigation routes ( not just link to 'admin' but also to 'admin/areas'. Not all users will have an access to all routes ... )

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CanActivate guard, import the child routes and unshit it to the routeConfig and call the resetConfig method.

You can find more details in this link https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11437

I hope that it can help.

Answer (score 0):

Aware this is a pretty old question, but for everybody looking for a solution of this use-case, as long as you don't have any dynamic routes on your module - you can just import
'**adminRoutes**' anywhere in your application and concat the '**path**' of the child-routes with the '**path**' of the top-level route.

No need to fiddle with your router-config in this case. Just try something like this:

```
import { routes } from 'path/to/top-level/routes';
import { dashboardRoutes } from 'path/to/dashboard-module/dashboard.module';
import { adminRoutes } from 'path/to/admin-module/admin.module';
@Component( ... )
export class FgViewBaseComponent {
    public topLevelRoutes = 
    public childRoutes = {
        '': dashboardRoutes
        'admin': adminRoutes
    }
    public getLinkText( topLevelRoutePath: string, childRoute: string = false ): string {
        ...
    }
    // CONSTRUCTOR
    constructor(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="route of routes">
    <a mat-button [routerLink]="[ route ]" routerLinkActive="active">{{ getLinkText( route ) }}</a>
    <ng-container *ngFor="childRoute of childRoutes[ route ]">
    <a mat-button [routerLink]="[ route, childRoute ]" routerLinkActive="active">{{ getLinkText( route, childRoute ) }}</a>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```